# How to display overlapping sets in Apache Superset?

Tags: visualization, apache-superset

I want to display how different sets of users relate to each other, how much they overlap, etc. Is it possible to do it in Apache Superset?

I have about 70 different Chart types to build but don't see anything like this.

I imagine it something like this. In case there were 2 sets of users and there were users in both sets, eg Mobile and Web users of the platform:
[image: two circles that overlap]